# Is c++ STL vector nth element finding significantly better with respect to page swapping than vector sort?

Tags: c++, vector, stl

I have some c++ code that can run into trouble if there are duplicate input points (points are pairs of doubles), and I can either sort the 2-d points with STL vector sort and then identify and remove duplicates as a preprocessing step, or I can let the code run (which is recursive) and modify it so that whenever it finds duplicates while running the main code, it removes them, and then reverts to base cases as necessary when the number of points is too low. However I don't want to do this unless it is worth it.

The thing is, my code already uses c++ STL vector nth element finding to find a median, and this is part of the divide-and-conquer recursion of the code. So my question is, in general, when a vector is too large to be processed all in memory at once, does c++ STL vector sorting typically create significantly more page swaps (either a constant factor multiplier, or asymptotically dominating multiplier) compared to c++ STL vector median finding? If not, then that would tell me I should stick with initial sorting to identify and remove duplicates.

Comment: Where did the duplicates come from in the first place?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit The code is meant for customers, and so the possibility of duplicates cannot be ruled out. But almost certainly, the number of duplicates, if there are any, will be quite small compared to the (potentially very large) data sets of points.

Comment: Make it so that duplicates can't be added, then you don't have to worry about it at all. It doesn't help that you're using floating point, mind you.

Comment: Anyway I think you'll find it extremely difficult to get a generic answer to this question. Too many factors are involved. Have you measured it on your target platform at varying degrees of load?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Yes but only memory usage that exceeds available memory by about 10-20% because page swapping takes so long. I hoped to find out what would happen if the code had to run for say, weeks, due to heavy page swapping. I could do a really long experiment to find out. Also, if it's dependent on too many factors to make general statements about various architectures and  OS's and versions of c++, I guess I'll save my programming time and stick with sorting because the alternative (dealing with dupes on the fly) would be fairly messy.

Comment: I had some experience with nth_element() / std::sort() for the same type of applications (duplicate points and KdTree). When there was the gcc4.8 bug in nth_element, I had to replace it with std::sort, it was just slightly slower (therefore I would not bother make the implementation more complicated in your case).

Comment: _"I could do a really long experiment to find out."_ You should.

Comment: _"the alternative (dealing with dupes on the fly) would be fairly messy"_ Not if you simply disallow them in the first place.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I don't have control over what data the customer will run the program on, so if they have dupes I can't really "disallow them" unless I preprocess to remove them. E.g. simply throwing an exception and crashing when a dupe is found along the way is not really an option for this code since it's going to be commercial.

Comment: @user2566092: You can make it part of the contract and then it's completely an option. If the contract says that it's valid to take in dupes but they will be ignored, then, yes, you have to do this wrangling yourself unfortunately. Commercialism doesn't seem relevant.